# Who activates the fasten seat belt warning on commercial flights?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation

Who activates (and de-activates) the "fasten seat belt" warning on commercial flights? I would guess it is either the pilot in command (normally the captain) or the first officer (co-pilot).

If the answer is airline specific, then answer for American Airlines.

Answer (score 4):

It's P1's decision, and P2's hand that moves the switch.
But, there's a really nice position of the switch, "Auto", which switches them on/off automatically based on some rules (which are usually passing through 10,000ft). Using the "Auto" position means that you can't forget them!

Comment: Yeah, well they forgot to turn it off on my last flight after we landed, so there is a problem with the "rules".

Comment: @Tyler Durden, how long did people remain in their seats after reaching the gate?

Comment: @MichaelHall how long do people remain in their seats after touching down??? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Depending to the Standard Operating Procedures of each airline, the **Pilot Flying** or the **Pilot in Command** will switch on the Fasten Seatbelts Sign, on takeoff, landing and when required mid-flight at their own discretion. Sometimes, the switch can be set to 'Auto' -if applicable-, which turns the Fasten Seatbelts sign off, once the flaps are set to the position 0 (Boeing Aircraft).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the pilot monitoring...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE. I'm sorry, but "I believe" do not constitute a good answer around here. Do you happen to have any sources that could help you expand your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Federico - I thought it might be a bit light... I'll go source it. But my knowledge is based on what I have seen happen - I said 'Believe' as different companies will have different procedures. I'll try get better info and edit.